# How can I assign different selection modes?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qheaderview

I have default QTableView. 
I want to get following selection behaviour:

1. If we selecting cells, selection will work like if we accepted `SelectionMode::ContiguousSelection`
2. If we selecting rows/column by clicking on QHeaderView section, selection will work like we accepted `SelectionMode::ExtendedSelection`, but deselect all cells, if any were selected.

I tried set SelectionMode to headers in QTableView constructor, but it doesn't work.

Question is how can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it.
All I had to do is just make custom selection model and handle everything in there. But I had to change `SelectionMode::ContiguousSelection`to `SelectionMode::ExtendedSelection` in my view to get meaningful indexes in my selection model.